# Prevent Save when Validation Errors occur on WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, validation, datagrid, relaycommand

Currently, I have a DataGrid which is bound to some data in my ViewModel. I have ValidationRules set up for the Rows, and the Columns. What I would like to do is prevent the user from saving the file if there are any Validation Errors. I am using the RelayCommands class to route the Open, Save, etc commands to my ViewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below links

[Disable Save button in WPF if validation fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757590/disable-save-button-in-wpf-if-validation-fails/757657#757657)

[Using WPF Validation rules and disabling a 'Save' button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/231052/217880)

http://babaandthepigman.wordpress.com/2010/02/14/wpf-commanding-and-data-annotations-validation/

Hope this helps...

Comment: link number 3 is dead

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the **BookLibrary** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. It disables the Save button when a validation error is active (e.g. DataGrid).