# What do parentheses in binding paths mean?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, syntax, parentheses

Recently i've read 'Databinding overview' article at MSDN and there is such sample code:

```
<TextBox.ToolTip>
  <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent"/>
</TextBox.ToolTip>
```

I know that `{}` means markup extensions but what mean `()` parentheses here? It would be nice someone share link to explanation such syntax. Thanks!

```
Path="(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `()` parentheses  refer to Attached Properties.

[Binding to an Attached Property](http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2008/01/15/binding-to-an-attached-property.aspx)

Comment: The actually _can_ refer to an attached property - but that's not the only case you would need them...

Answer (score 7):

Quoting the [MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451.aspx#singleattached) (I'm quoting MSDN here because I couldn't have written it down better):

> This syntax is generally used for one of the following cases:
>
> - The path is specified in XAML that is in a style or template that does not have a specified `TargetType`. A qualified usage is generally not valid for cases other than this, because in non-style, non-template cases, the property exists on an instance, not a type.
> - The property is an attached property.
> - You are binding to a static property.
>
> For use as storyboard target, the property specified as `propertyName` must be a `DependencyProperty`.

Answer (score 5):

`(Validation.Errors)` references the attached property `Errors` in the `Validation` class. Since the binding has a `RelativeSource = Self`, it's gonna look for the value of that attached property with respect to the TextBox itself.

Answer (score 0):

This below msdn link is neatly explaining about the validation rule and sequences as well as how to use.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.errors.aspx