# Why Validation.HasError must be in brackets?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

Im learning validations in WPF and got one question, when I want to check in XAML if any control has any errors and unblock smth if so then I can write for example something like this code snippet:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=tx2, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="false">
      <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

What interest me is the part :

```
   Path=(Validation.HasError)
```

Why do I have to put this in brackets? When I bind for example :

```
 <TextBlock Text={Binding ElementName=myTextBlock, Path=Text.Length}/>
```

I dont need brackets but Im also using the smth.smth syntax, then why Validation.HasError mut be in "( )" ?

Comment: Attached dependency properties need to have `()` to be bound

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.110).aspx see here

Comment: Info about binding syntax here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc645024(v=vs.95).aspx#attacheddata

Comment: @Charleh: Why the heck don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: Because it probably needs to be marked a dupe but I'm too lazy to search for a dupe :)

Comment: @Charleh: Here's one then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382581/wpf-syntax-what-parentheses-means (Also: You should use @-notation if you want comments in someone else's post reach another's inbox)