# Add MouseMove event if value is true

Tags: c#, wpf, button, mouseevent

I have DataTemplate selector for my ItemsControl and I'd like to achieve something like:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="buttonTemplate">
            <Button if(someValue = true -> add thisPreviewMouseUp="button_MouseUp") PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="button_MouseLeftButtonUp" PreviewMouseMove="button_MouseMove" Click="b_Click">
                <Button.Content>
                    <Image Source="sample.png" Height="{Binding height}" Width="{Binding width}" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Button.Content>
                <Button.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding angle}" />
                </Button.RenderTransform>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Users can move, change size of buttons from manager mode, but I don't want to fire this event in normal mode (now there is if(_fromWhere == "MANAGER") in mouse_move event)

Any idea how can I make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if it's possible in XAML to set event to be fired or not.

However you can set `someValue` in [Tag property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag.aspx) of button and then in fired event check for Tag as proposed in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006507/add-parameter-to-button-click-event).

```
    <Button Tag="{Binding someValue}" ...>
```

In event handler:

```
    bool someValue = (bool)(((Button)sender).Tag);
```

**Edit 1:**

An alternative way would be to get the DataContext of button if someValue is part of DataContext of button:

```
    var dataContext = ((Button)e.OriginalSource).DataContext;
    if (dataContext.someValue) 
    {
        ...
    }
```

**Edit 2:**

After a little investigation I found out that it is possible to add MouseMove event depending on `someValue`. Unfortunately it is unnecessarily complex I think.

```
     <Button Style="{Binding someValue, Converter={StaticResource BoolToButtonStyleConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource MousePreviewEventSetStyle}, Mode=OneWay}" ...>
```

In Window.Resources define this:

```
    <l:BoolToButtonStyleConverter x:Key="BoolToButtonStyleConverter" />
    <Style x:Key="MousePreviewEventSetStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseUp" Handler="PreviewMouseUpClicked" />
    </Style>
```

And then in Application.Resources define this:

```
    <Style x:Key="clearStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" />
```

After all you have to define:

```
    public class BoolToButtonStyleConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool someValue = (bool)value;

            if (someValue)
                return parameter;
            else
                return Application.Current.Resources["clearStyle"];
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Finally set the handler for event:

```
    void PreviewMouseUpClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Memo: Probably there is better way to set "default style" to button that define "clear style".

Answer (score 0):

Might help.

Mvvm Approach

I think easy way of doing this , Enable the Event only when a condition is true.

what i'm doing here i Execute a a Command Named **DropUser** when Event **Drop Occurs**. I used mvvmlight for easy commanding . you can use ICommand Wpf default commanding [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032689/button-doesnt-become-disabled-when-command-canexecute-is-false)

```
xmlns:interactivity="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:mvvmlight="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"


    <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="Drop">
                                        <mvvmlight:EventToCommand 
                                            Command="{Binding DataContext.DropUser, 
                                            PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                                    </interactivity:EventTrigger>
                                </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
```

ViewModel

```
 #region RelayCommand

    private RelayCommand<DragEventArgs> _dropUser;
    public RelayCommand<DragEventArgs> DropUser
    {
        get
        {
           return _dropUser ?? (_dropUser = new RelayCommand<DragEventArgs>(DropMethod,canExecute));
        }

    }

    private bool canExecute(DragEventArgs arg)
    {
        // check your condition return true . Command is only work when you return true.
    }

    #endregion

 // Method Will Fire here and do action here
 private void DropMethod(DragEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (eventArgs != null)
        {
        }
    }
```

what you need is like this.

```
<interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                                        <mvvmlight:EventToCommand 
                                            Command="{Binding CommandName, 
                                            PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                                    </interactivity:EventTrigger>
                                </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Viewmodel

```
 private RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs> _commandName;

    public RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs>CommandName
    {
        get
        {
            return commandName ?? (commandName = new RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs>(invokeAction, canExecuteMethod));
        }


    }

    private bool canExecuteMethod()
    {
          check your condition return true
    }

    private void invokeAction(RoutedEventArgs event)
    {
        action you want to do 
    }
```