# How to execute some action on  TextBox.Triggers (event trigger)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have to disable a some button.

How I can use **TextBox.Triggers** for that?

Are there any samples?

Thank you for reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have a `TextBox` and a `Button`, and you want to disable your `Button` when `TextBox` is empty. This can be easily achieved with `DataTriggers`:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" />
<Button>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox}" Value="">
                    <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Your solution is the best one! Ty!

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming this is related to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976475/how-to-disable-a-button-based-on-the-validationrule-class) about triggering the Enabled property on a Button based on if a TextBox has a validation error or not.

If that's so, you would use a `DataTrigger` to test the `TextBox.Validation.HasError` property to see if it has any errors, and if so disable the Button

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyTextBox, Path=Validation.HasError" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style>
```

Be sure you bind your TextBox with `ValidatesOnDataErrors="True"` for this to work

```
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Text="{Binding SomeText, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True }" />
```

As a side note, my comment on your other question still applies here. I would personally implement `IDataErrorInfo` in your `ViewModel` and make the `SaveCommand.CanExecute()` only return true if `ViewModel.IsValid`. Then it will automatically take care of disabling the button if the `SaveCommand` is not supposed to execute

Comment: Thank you Rachel for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Although posting code sample would be helpful and would allow a much better solution, I can still recommend [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).  Something like

```
<Button Name="btnFoo"
        Enabled="{Binding ElementName=txtblkBar, Converter={StaticResource ButtonVisibilityConverter}"/>
```

where the resources section of your control contains

```
<local:ButtonVisibilityConverter Name="ButtonVisibilityConverter"/>
```

and you have defined a class `ButtonVisibilityConverter` in the namespace referenced by local.  The Data Conversion section of the page I linked to above has an example converter class.

**EDIT:**

Code that sets the button to disabled whenever `txtblkBar` is empty:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(TextBlock), typeof(bool?))]
public class ButtonVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        TextBlock txtblk = value as TextBlock;
        if (null == txtblk)
            return false;
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtblk.Text);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Don't need to use the back conversion
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great!!!! Can u put more code about how to implement ButtonVisibilityConverter, please?

Comment: I suggest [String.IsNullOrEmpty Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx).
`return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtblk.Text);`

Comment: -1 because you should use the right tool for the job. Use a `Converter` if you want to Convert the value from one type to another. Use a `DataTrigger` if you want to change a value based on a condition. The question is asking how to change a value based on a condition.

Comment: So you are binding `Enabled` using a `ButtonVisibilityConverter` and the class posted is named `ColorBrushConverter`, which returns a bool, which I would have never guessed from the name.  Further, why are you relying on sending in a TextBlock to the converter?  Why not bind to the TextBlock's Text property in XAML, then the Converter is more reusable.

Comment: @cadrell0 The name is a typo that resulted from copy-pasting existing code.  Fixed.